# Should MAX in Group By Retrieve the Whole Row Data

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a bunch of sql columns to retrieve. This is my SQL statement:

```
     SELECT b.iposx_model_id,
             a.mrModel, MAX(a.mrRevision) as mrRevision, a.mrApprovedBy, ...
      FROM mydb1.tbl_model_revision a
     INNER JOIN  mydb2.model_from_revision_process b 
             ON b.mrModel = a.mrModel 
     WHERE a.mrType = 1
     GROUP BY a.mrModel
     ORDER BY b.iposx_model_id ASC
```

On a certain mrModel column taht I retrieved, these are the data that I'm querying for:

[image]

In my query, it states that I should get the data with the Max mrRevision which corresponds to the third row.

However, upon running the sql statement, I got the max mrRevision which is 2, coming from the third row. But the other column data I get came from the 2nd row, an example is mrApprovedBy which is 1035 instead of 10. Why is that happening?

Comment: if they are in same table, then it is not possible.

Comment: `In my query, it states that I should get the data with the Max mrRevision which corresponds to the third row.` - that's slightly incorrect. Your query returns maximum of `mrRevision` only. To get the row which corresponds to the maximum `mrRevision` you need to specify it in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the picture is just a select statement from a specific mrModel. Now, I run the Max(mrRevision), I should get all the data of the 3rd row in the picture since it has the highest mrRevision, right? Am I wrong?

Comment: @user5226582 What should I specify in my WHERE clause?

Comment: No, see above. You could specify `MAX` of each column at the same time.

Comment: I don't really need MAX of each column. I just need all the data of the rows that has the MAX mrRevision per mrModel

Comment: I just gave that example to illustrate that `MAX()` does not select a single row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use  group by for only a part of the column not involved  in aggegation function is select clause 
is depreacted in SQL because where work  produce unpredicatble result

In most DB and in the most recent version of mysql  this use of group by  is not allowed

for obtain the row corresponding to the max value  you could use a join on the values that match the right content

```
SELECT 
    b.iposx_model_id
    , a.mrModel
    , t.mrRevision
    , a.mrApprovedBy
    , ...
FROM mydb1.tbl_model_revision a
 JOIN ( 
select  mrModel, MAX(mrRevision) as mrRevision
from mydb1.tbl_model_revision
GROUP BY a.mrModel 
) t on a.mrModel = t.mrModel and a.mrRevision = t.mrRevision
 JOIN mydb2.model_from_revision_process b ON b.mrModel = a.mrModel 
WHERE a.mrType = 1
ORDER BY b.iposx_model_id ASC
```

Comment: I think I'm getting you. So, Group by should only be used on the exact specific columns that I needed to have a group by query. The other data belonging to the same row should be fetched using a JOIN.

Comment: Can you format your SQL code? There are duplicating Phrases.

Comment: @KaySingian   yes . the code was courtesy corrected by strawberry